# Python web scraping - print only part of url

Tags: python, regex, url, web, screen-scraping

I have a Python web scraping program which gets all links from given sites and I've managed to print out the domain name of each link and path after that.

The code:

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import cookielib

url = "http://www.sparkbrowser.com"

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
page = br.open(url, timeout=5)

htmlcontent = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)


for link in br.links(text_regex=re.compile('^((?!IMG).)*$')):
    newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
    base = link.base_url
    print base," - ",newurl
```

and it gets me results like this:

```
http://www.sparkbrowser.com  -  http://www.sparkbrowser.com
http://www.sparkbrowser.com  -  http://sparkbrowser.com
http://www.sparkbrowser.com  -  http://www.sparkbrowser.com/index.php
http://www.sparkbrowser.com  -  http://www.sparkbrowser.com/download.php
http://www.sparkbrowser.com  -  http://www.sparkbrowser.com/about.php
http://www.sparkbrowser.com  -  http://www.sparkbrowser.com/features.php
http://www.sparkbrowser.com  -  http://www.sparkbrowser.com/spark.php

etc....
```

I was wondering how to get only `sparkbrowser.com` or `sparkbrowser` only from the given address?

I know how to separate the domain name, `http://www.sparkbrowser.com` and the path, but I don't know if it is possible to print parts of URL as I mentioned

I've tried something with Regex but I was not successful.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`urlparse.urlsplit()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) to split out the URL into constituent parts:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlsplit
>>> urlsplit('http://www.sparkbrowser.com/index.php')
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.sparkbrowser.com', path='/index.php', query='', fragment='')
>>> _.netloc
'www.sparkbrowser.com'
```

You can then split the `.netloc` value further if desired:

```
>>> '.'.join(res.netloc.split('.')[-2:])
'sparkbrowser.com'
```

or, (better), use the [`publicsuffix` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffix/) to extract the public suffix of a given domain name:

```
>>> from publicsuffix import PublicSuffixList
>>> psl = PublicSuffixList()
>>> psl.get_public_suffix(res.netloc)
'sparkbrowser.com'
>>> psl.get_public_suffix('www.example.domain.co.uk')
'domain.co.uk'
```

Comment: this will use me... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

newurl.split('.com')[1] should do the trick.